# Unable to add Class Library in WebAPI Project which is developed in .NET Core 1.1

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a **WebAPI application developed in .NET Core 1.1**. I am trying to add a Class Library which was developed in .NET 4.5.1 into WebAPI Project. Added the "Class Library Project Reference" into WebAPI project, but when I am trying to Instantiate (or trying to add the namespace of Class Library) the class which is not coming in WebAPI Project. 
Again Developed the Class Library in .NET Core 1.1, but I am facing the same problem.

Kindly help me where did I wrong?

Performance wise which is Best - **.NET Core Class Library** or **.NET 4.5.1 Class Library** for WebAPI which is developed in .NET Core.

*(this class library will hold business logic)*

Thanks in advance for your help.

Best Regards,
DG

Comment: As for performance, there are no differences, both compile to roughly the same CIL Code. Performance gains come from the runtime (.NET COre vs. .NET Framework 4.x) not from project types

Comment: Thanks. Will use .NET Core for future Project.